# submitting text string from within accordion panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am displaying accordion dynamically and inside each "collapsable panel" in the accordion, I am trying to generate text boxes dynamically for each Panel when someone clicks on the "+ Add more commands" button for each of the Panels. I am using a custom JQuery script below to create text input dynamically..

[image]

**JADE:**

```
#accordion.panel-group
each item in session.intents
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-heading
      h4.panel-title
        a(data-toggle='collapse', data-parent='#accordion', href='#collapse' + item) #{item}
    div(id="collapse#{item}").panel-collapse.collapse
      .panel-body
        .col-lg-6
          .my-form
            form(role='form', method='post')
              .text-box
                .form-group.input-group
                  span.input-group-addon
                    i.glyphicon.glyphicon-comment
                  input#box1.form-control(type='text', name='boxes[]', placeholder='Give a sample command..')
                  a.input-group-btn
                    button.remove-box.btn.btn-primary(type='button')
                      i.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash

              .add-box(href='#') 
                button.btn.btn-primary(type='button')
                  i.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
                  |           Add more commands
              p
                button.btn.btn-primary(type='button')
                  i.glyphicon.glyphicon-save
                  |           Save commands
```

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
      var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
      var box_html = $('<div class="text-box"><div class="form-group input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Give an app name.." name="boxes[]" id="box1"><a class="input-group-btn"><button class="remove-box btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button></a></div></div>');
      box_html.hide();
      if (n > 1) {
          $('.my-form .text-box:last').after(box_html);
      } else {
          $('.my-form').append(box_html);
      }
      box_html.fadeIn('slow');
      return false;
  });
  $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
      $(this).parent().parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
      $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
          $(this).remove();
          $('.box-number').each(function(index){
              $(this).text( index + 1 );
          });
      });
      return false;
  });
  $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box-out', function(){
      $(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
      $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
          $('.box-number').each(function(index){
              $(this).text( index + 1 );
          });
      });
      return false;
  });
```

});

When I click the "Add more commands" Button below, it adds more text input boxes, but only under the second panel (and not under the first panel).

Questions:

1. How can I add dynamic text boxes to each of the two Panels?
2. How can I pass some information to the model telling it what panel the text value is coming from (Panel1 or Panel2)?

Comment: add a hidden field `panel_id`, find that field nearest to click `$(this)` on a panel button `click` and pass it to `popup`.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.my-form .text-box:last')` is always selecting the very last textbox, so if you have the two panels in the same my-form, only the last one of the last panel will be selected. So **change** your selector into something that adds the new text box to the end of the parent of the textboxes instead of after the last text box.

Comment: thanks! But, how can I change the JS and the corresponding to achieve that? Also, when i submit the form how can I tell which panel it came from/

Comment: I've never used jade, so unless you can show the html that jade template creates, I can't really help with that alas.